# How catch changes in scope variable made in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some directive for html:

```
<dropdown placeholder='' list='sizeWeightPriceArr' selected='selectedProductSize' property='size' value='size' style='width:60px;'></dropdown>
```

selectedProductSize => scope variable. Basic idea => I selected some value in dropdown and this variable in selected attribute save all changes.
JS:

```
.directive('dropdown', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "templates/dropdown.html",
        scope: {
            placeholder: "@",
            list: "=",
            selected: "=",
            property: "@",
            value: "@"
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.listVisible = false;
            scope.isPlaceholder = true;

            scope.select = function(item) {
                scope.isPlaceholder = false;
                scope.selected = item[scope.value];
                scope.listVisible = false;

            };

            scope.isSelected = function(item) {                                                                                      
                return item[scope.value] === scope.selected;
            };

            scope.show = function() {
                scope.listVisible = true;
            };

            $rootScope.$on("documentClicked", function(inner, target) {
                if(!$(target[0]).is(".dropdown-display.clicked") && !$(target[0]).parents(".dropdown-display.clicked").length > 0) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        scope.listVisible = false;
                    });
                }
            });                     

            scope.$watch('selected', function(value) {
                if(scope.list != undefined) {
                    angular.forEach(scope.list, function(objItem) {
                        if(objItem[scope.value] == scope.selected) {
                            scope.isPlaceholder = objItem[scope.property] === undefined;
                            scope.display = objItem[scope.property];
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            scope.$watch('list', function(value) {
                angular.forEach(scope.list, function(objItem) {
                    if(objItem[scope.value] == scope.selected) {
                        scope.isPlaceholder = objItem[scope.property] === undefined;
                        scope.display = objItem[scope.property];
                    }
                });
            });

        }
    }
}])
```

dropdown.html don't irrelevant. When I make selection `scope.select` function run inside directive and in `scope.selected = item[scope.value];` set selected value. It is working. Then in controller I try to write `$scope.$watch` to catch changes and run function but it won't work:

```
$scope.selectedProductSize = '';
$scope.$watch('selectedProductSize', function(value) {
    ...                     
});
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle for this? This seems correct when just looking at what you are showing here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to user `$watch` you can pass in the variable to the directive with two way data binding

in your controller

```
$scope.my_var = ''
```

directive html

```
myvar=my_var
```

directive

```
scope: {
  myvar: '='
}
```

`$scope.my_var` will be bound to the directive `myvar` so anytime `scope.myvar` changes in your directive, `$scope.my_var` will also be updated in your controller

Comment: This is I understand. But basic Idea in controller run watch function on this variable. And if this variable places in scope in won't work, if variable inside object that inside scope all working. I do not understand why?